# Laravel change language depending on a $_GET parameter

Tags: laravel, localization, middleware, getparameter

A simple scenario when we want to setup the Locale Language settings (App::setLocale()) depending on a $_GET parameter as in following URL:

http://aboutlaravel.com/?language_code=en

**Possible Solution:** Create a middleware and register it in app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class
    ],
```

The Localization middleware will look like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(isset($_GET['language_code'])) {
        if ($_GET['language_code'] == "en") {
            App::setLocale("en");
        } else if ($_GET['language_code'] == "de") {
            App::setLocale("de");
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PHP *>= 7.0* you can use a very nice one liner.

Just use this:

```
App::setLocale(request('langauge_code', 'en'));

// en is the default if request has no language_code
```

Voilà :)

Comment: if you want to keep your qs clean, you can use `App::setLocale($request->header('Accept-Language'));`

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the question, but I think you need it.

```
   if(empty($request->input('language_code'))) {
        // set "en" as default language
        App::setLocale("en");
    } else {
        App::setLocale($request->input('language_code'));
    }
```

Comment: The mark for checking the empty string is correct! The question is how can you do it in a better aproach :)

Comment: One line case 
`App::setLocale(empty($request->input('language_code')) ? 'en' : $request->input('language_code'))`