# How to create a multi language website with Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

What is the best way to setup a multi language website with Laravel?
The URL must contain the language (nl, fr, en). For example: mywebsite.com/en/faq.
Most examples and tutorials I find use the session to store the current language which is completely useless of course. I should be able to directly link to a page in a specific language.

I could create a route per language but that does not really seem like a good idea. Ideally this could be made dynamic in order to easily create more locales.

Comment: Can you check this post: [How to create Laravel localization](https://devnote.in/how-to-create-laravel-localization/)

Comment: @FefarRavi I'm sure this will work in a way but the locale is stored in a parameter instead of in the url path itself. This uses a new router just to change the locale and this is just too restrictive for my needs.
Thanks for replying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the laravel-localization package by mcamara.
Seems to do everything I need.
I'm not really sure why anyone would try to build their own version if this exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, create route with locale group and locale middleware

Route should look like this
[image]

And then in your middleware set the language based on the `locale` parameter.

We can pick dynamic url segment using `request()->route('')`

[image]

#### Note: You need to pass locale value when you call route() helper.

Maybe there is another better approach to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious, why you cannot use session (it's a true question, I really would like to understand)?

You can use the same approach than with session: create a middleware to set App::setLocale("YourLanguage") based on query string.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    // This example try to get "language" variable, \
    // if it not exist will define pt as default \
    // you also can use some config value: replace 'pt' by Config::get('app.locale')

    App::setLocale(request('language', 'pt'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

Or you can do it by Route:

```
// This example check the if the language exist in an array before apply
Route::get('/{language?}', function ($language = null) {
    if (isset($language) && in_array($language, config('app.available_locales'))) {
        app()->setLocale($language);
    } else {
      app()->setLocale(Config::get('app.locale'));
    }
    
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Source:

[Laravel change language depending on a $_GET parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201562/laravel-change-language-depending-on-a-get-parameter)

https://lokalise.com/blog/laravel-localization-step-by-step/

Comment: Doing it with a session just seems really weird because this should not be linked to a session. The language is defined by the URL. If I post an URL on social media in a specific language I want people to go the that exact language. I don't want them to go to the default language first where they need to find the language switch.

Honestly I'm a little confused why a well known PHP framework has no built in way to handle this. Everyone seems to throw something together in a different way in order to have a multi language website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mcamara Laravel localization package. it'll do everything you need.
And here's the package link:

https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization